# Need clarifications about a match context of an erlang bitstring

Tags: erlang

I'd read [efficiency guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/users_guide.html) and [erlang-questions mailing list archive](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/) &
all of the available books in erlang. But I haven't found the precise description of efficient
binaries pattern matching. Though, I haven't read sources yet :) But I hope
that people, who already have read them, would read this post. Here are my questions.

1. How many match contexts does an erlang binary have?

   a) if we match parts of a binary sequentially and just once

   ```
   A = <<1,2,3,4>>.
   <<A1,A2,A3,A4>> = A.
   ```

   Do we have just one binary match context(moving from the beginning of A to the end), or four?

   b) if we match parts of a binary sequentially from the beginning to the end for the first time
   and(sequentially again) from the beginning to the end for the second time

   ```
   B = <<1,2,3,4>>.
   <<B1,B2,B3,B4>> = B.
   <<B11,B22,B33,B44>> = B.
   ```

   Do we have just a single match context, which is moving from the beginning of B to the end
   of B and then moving again from the beginning of B to the end of B,

   or

   we have 2 match contexts, one is moving from the beginning of B to the end of B,
   and another - again from the beginning of B to the end of B (as first can't move
   to the beginning again)

   or we have 8 match contexts?
2. According to [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/binaryhandling.html#id65745), if I write:

   ```
   my_binary_to_list(<<H,T/binary>>) ->
       [H|my_binary_to_list(T)];
   my_binary_to_list(<<>>) -> [].
   ```

   there will be only 1 match context for the whole recursion tree, even though, this
   function isn't tail-recursive.

   a) Did I get it right, that there would be only 1 match context in this case?

   b) Did I get right, that if I match an erlang binary sequentially(from the beginning to 
   the end), it doesn't matter which recursion type(tail or body) has to be used?(from the binary-matching efficiency point of view)

   c) What if I'm going to process erlang binary NOT sequentially, say, I'm travelling through
   a binary - first I match first byte, then 1000th, then 5th, then 10001th, then 10th...

   In this case,

   d1) If I used body-recursion, how many matching contexts for this binary would I have - 
   one or >1?

   d2) if I used tail-recursion, how many matching contexts for this binary would I have - 
   one or >1?
3. If I pass a large binary(say 1 megabyte) via tail recursion, Will all the 1 megabyte data be copied? Or only a some kind of pointer to the beginning of this binary is being passed between calls?
4. Does it matter which binary I'm matching - big or small - a match context will be created for binary of any size or only for large ones?

Comment: This question got an answer on http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/How-does-a-match-context-of-an-erlang-bitstring-work-td4690729.html#a4690748

Answer (score 1):

I am only a beginner in erlang, so take this answer with a grain of salt.

1. > How many match contexts does an erlang binary have?

   a) Only one context is created, but it is entirely consumed in that instance, since there's nothing left to match, and thus it may not be reused.

   b) Likewise, the whole binary is split, there are no context left after matching, though one context has been created for each line: the assignments of `B1` up to `B4` creates one context, and the second set of assignments from `B11` to `B44` does also create a context. So in total we get 2 context created and consumed.
2. > According to documentation [...]

   *This section isn't quite totally clear for me as well, but this is what I could figure out.*

   a) Yes, there will be only one context allocated for the whole duration of the function recursive execution.

   b) Indeed no mention is made of distinguishing tail recursion vs non tail recursion. However, the example given is clearly a function which can be transformed (though it's not trivial) into a tail-recursive one. I suppose that the compiler decides to duplicate a matching context when a clause contains more than one path for the context to follow. In that case, the compiler detects that the function is tail optimizable, and goes without doing the allocation.

   c) We see the opposite situation happening in the example following the one you've reproduced, which contains a case expression: there, the context may follow 2 different paths, thus the compiler has to force the allocation at each recursion level.
3. > If I pass a large binary (say 1 megabyte) via tail recursion [...]

   From § 4.1:

   > *A sub binary is created by split_binary/2 and when a binary is matched out in a binary pattern. A sub binary is a reference into a part of another binary (refc or heap binary, never into a another sub binary). Therefore, matching out a binary is relatively cheap because the actual binary data is never copied.*

   When dealing with binaries, a buffer is used to store the actual data, and any matching of sub-part is implemented as a structure containing a pointer to the original buffer, plus an offset and a length indicating which sub part is being considered. That's the sub binary type being mentioned in the docs.
4. Does it matter which binary I'm matching - big or small - ...

   From that same § 4.1:

   > *The binary containers are called refc binaries (short for reference-counted binaries) and heap binaries.*
   >
   > *Refc binaries consist of two parts: an object stored on the process heap, called a ProcBin, and the binary object itself stored outside all process heaps.*

   [...]

   > *Heap binaries are small binaries, up to 64 bytes, that are stored directly on the process heap. They will be copied when the process is garbage collected and when they are sent as a message. They don't require any special handling by the garbage collector.*

   This indicates that depending on the size of the binary, it may be stored as a big buffer outside of processes, and referenced in the processes through a proxy structure, or if that binary is **64 bytes of less**, it will be stored directly in the process memory dealing with it. The first case avoids copying the binary when processes sharing it are running on the same node.